# Clicking on tabs does not switch current tab when using Android TabLayout

Tags: android

Am I supposed to set onClicks myself, and if so, where should I do that?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Show us your java code.

Comment: Do I actually have to implement onClick listeners for every tab? Or is it done automatically?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The main problem is, the `ViewPager` overlays the `TabLayout`. So, you should place it below `TabLayout`:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"/>
```

And from the Activity's onCreate method, call:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

For more details, check this example:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/MainActivity.java

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml

Answer (score 27):

Try setting the viewpagers current item using the tab layouts tab selected listener.

```
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: It asks me to make viewPager final? I should totally go with it right?

Comment: You can set it as final or you could make viewPager a variable of the class and not just a local variable in onCreateView or wherever you are setting it up

Comment: its weird though, nothing changes when selecting tabs

Comment: `setOnTabSelectedListener()` is deprecated. Use this method `addOnTabSelectedListener()`

Answer (score 5):

This issue had been fixed in support library version 24.0.0

Check the link : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201659

You can update your library.

Comment: v4 support library or v7 support library?